# Kubernetes: Find when a ConfigMap was patched

Tags: kubernetes

I can easily find when a ConfigMap was created but how do you find out when a ConfigMap was last patched (edited)?

That information does not appear in any of the metadata when I export as YAML.

Deployments have a `lastUpdateTime` field that we can see, ConfigMaps don't appear to have the same, is that true?

```
status:
  availableReplicas: 2
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-01-16T17:48:17Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-01-16T17:48:17Z"
```

Answer (score 6):

By current design config maps are not versioned and so there is no preserving the history and at a given point in time there can be only one version of a ConfigMap in kubernetes. Deployments are versioned and needs history and timestamps for rollout and rollback.

Comment: Thanks!  Not thinking about rollbacks so much as a better audit trail.  @rabello has the fix for that below though

Answer (score 4):

As @ArghyaSadhu said, configmaps are not versioned in kubernetes.

If you want to take control of your configmaps versions, you could create a simple entry in the data field like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data: 
  config.version: "001" <== HERE
...
```

and increase/modify the version number of this specific data when you do some adjustment or just let your CI/CD process modify it for you.

But it is the only for your control, if you want to implement 'rollback' functionality to your configmaps this must be done using some script from your side.

Comment: Good idea.  Will look into implementing something like that.  It's not for rollback rather more auditing purposes.